# Classification or regression? Which model is more accurate if I only care about being above or under the threshold?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression

If I have a regression problem that can also be a classification problem by converting a continuous variable to a binary depending on a threshold, which model would be more accurate if I only care about being above or under the threshold?

Example: I have a column with house prices [20, 30, 40, 70] but I only care if the house is expensive (more than 40) or cheap (less than 40)

Comment: When you say 'threshoold,' are you talking about support vectors, as in SVC and SVR? There are many regression and classification methods; you need to specify which methods you would like to compare.

Comment: If you turn it to classification, how many classes you would have?

Comment: For this case is two, but I am also interested in other cases.

Comment: It highly depends on your hypothesis you want to predict. But I guess regression problems are so much difficult than classification, classification tasks usually need decision boundary whilst regression problems should accurately predict the result for each entry point in the feature space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classification is the more direct approach and it will likely give better results. This is because the model's goal is exactly the same as your goal - i.e. predicting whether the price is above or below the threshold - and it will maximize this accuracy.

A regression model that is trying to minimize MSE, for example, could give you a model that doesn't accurately put predictions on the correct side of the threshold - which it doesn't know or care about. The model does not have the same goal as you do.

Let's construct a very simple example to see why this might be the case:

```
Training     Test 
x      y     x      y
1.0    20    1.8    ?
2.0    20    2.4    ?
3.0    200   2.8    ?
4.0    200   3.2    ?
```

Here I used the rule `if x<2.5: y=20, else y=200` to generate the data.

A maximum-margin classifier would get all of the test examples right, but a linear regression model fit on the training data would get all of the test examples wrong.